Toast function cannot find its div
Hello I have this error where the toast alert is not showing on the page when I log in but it is when I sign out, any idea why it does this? I tried multiple things like logging the toastLiveExample and the toastBody but it always returns null when I sign in showToast("text-bg-success", ${username}, you have successfully signed in! Check out your <a href="/profile/${username}">profile</a>!);
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')
at showToast (toast.js:6:20)
at HTMLDocument. (sign-in?id=...)
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" re
  <div id="alert"></div>

   
  <!--bootstrap code-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--alert code-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $("#alert").load("/staticHtml/toast.html");
  </script>
  <!-- toast function -->
  <script src="/js/toast.js"></script>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
      try {
        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const token = urlParams.get("token");

        if (token) {
          const id = urlParams.get("id");
          const username = urlParams.get("username");

          let params = {
            _id: id,
            username,
            token,
          };

          showToast("text-bg-success", `${username}, you have successfully signed in! Check out your <a href="/profile/${username}">profile</a>!`);
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(params));
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        showToast("text-bg-danger", "Something went wrong");
      }
    });
  </script>

function showToast(toastType, message) {
  const toastLiveExample = document.getElementById("liveToast");
  const toastBody = document.getElementById("toastBody");
  const toastBootstrap = bootstrap.Toast.getOrCreateInstance(toastLiveExample);

  toastLiveExample.classList.add(toastType);
  toastBody.innerHTML = message;
  toastBootstrap.show();
}

<div class="toast-container position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3">
  <div id="liveToast" class="toast align-items-center" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="toast-body" id="toastBody">Hello, world! This is a toast message.</div>
      <i class="fa fa-times me-2 m-auto" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


May I direct you to the guidance about posting "[mcve]" code, with an emphasis on the "minimal"? Once you've read that, please [edit] your question to reduce all the code that's unnecessary to your problem. With less to read through, and parse, you're likely to get more concise answers better tailored to your specific problem.

Alr sure, I'll edit it.

When and how is that lower html snippet added to the DOM? document.getElementById("liveToast")  returning null can only have one reason: When the code is executed, there is no element with that id contained in the DOM.

Please click [edit] then the button marked [<>] and make a snippet

Snippet to what?

The problem is that jQuery load() is asynchronous, so showToast runs before the toast.html is added to the DOM, as correctly pointed out in the comments (and also it doesn't fall under DOMContentLoaded listener).
So, you need to wait for it to be loaded, and only then run your code.
A quick-and-drity way would be to make a synchronous request:
$("#alert").html(
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'staticHtml/toast.html',
    async: false
}).responseText
);

or you could refactor the code and use promises, which is a bit more verbose, for example:
function loadToast() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        $("#alert").load("staticHtml/toast.html", () => {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}


//...
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {

 await loadToast();


OMG this fixed my problem, man you saved me! I've been tampering with this problem for over 2 days now! You're a life saver. But thanks for the explanation too, I though in html it would load when the other code is fired but I guess not.

no, because AJAX loading and DOM loading are not connected, there are good posts here on SO, here's one: Wait for ajax done in document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'), or Does AJAX loaded content get a "document.ready"?

thank you, will definitely check these out!
